# I need a user to enter a string and said string should be stored in a struct variable in C

Tags: c, string, struct

I have to create an athlete management system. I am fairly new to C so pardon me being a noob and asking silly questions. So when I accept all the input for an athlete it prints the string components as a heart emoji. So changed it to use strcpy() but when I do this the program crashes after I input the name. so idk how else to store the user inputted name.

```
typedef struct athlete
{
char name[100];
int id;
int age;
}ath;
```

this is my struct

```
do
{
    printf("Please enter the participant's name:\n");
    scanf("%s",aname);

    for ( i = 0; i < strlen(aname); i++ ){
        if(isalpha(aname[i]) == 0){
            printf("here");
            printf("Name is invalid! Please re-enter the name\n");
            j = 1;
        }
        else{
            printf("Here");

            a.name = strdup(aname);
            j = 0;
        }
    }


} while(j==1);
```

this is my validation and user input section

so after the name is entered it crashes (none of the here print statements are executed so I  really do not know what to do or if  I missed a step along the way any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn’t use `strdup` since you don’t need to allocate anything and using it will cause issues. What is `aname` here?

Comment: If `a` is a `ath`, this code shouldn't even *compile* much less run to a crash. You cannot direct-assign to an array, `a.name`, in C.

Comment: Your compiler is complaining about the line `a.name = strdup(name);` — heed its warnings.  It may also be complaining about other lines — heed those warnings too.  Avoid posting code that doesn't compile cleanly under stringent warnings — or, if you don't understand the warnings, post the minimal code that reproduces the warning along with the actual warnings produced for the code shown in the question.  Compilers don't give warnings unless they've spotted a bug in your code.  At this stage in your career, assume the compiler is omniscient and infallible.

Comment: Replace `a.name = strdup(aname)` with `strcpy(a.name, aname)`, assuming `aname` is the same size as (or smaller than) `a.name`.

Comment: Yogi, "so after the name is entered" --> what did you enter - or may enter?  A name with spaces in it?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen its a variable in a function (to register an athlete). basically where the user enters the all the details about the athlete I used it in the scanf because when i do a.name i get errors

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i tried that before this method and that didnt work.

Comment: @WhozCraig could you expound a bit on that ?

Comment: Remove `strlen(aname)` out of the loop. It counts the same number of characters each time around the loop. Bung summat like `int length = strlen(aname)` before the loop and use that variable instead

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica after that the program just stops and then closes i don't get to input anything else. In terms of what you may enter its the just the name but now that you mention it i will have to edit the code accordingly thank you for pointing that out

Comment: @Yogi Rather than only say " just the name", please provide examples.

Comment: at the moment it would accept a name which is any sequence of characters but if a space is added it just runs the next block of code indefinitely

Answer (score -1):

Try something like:
do
{
printf("Please enter the participant's name:\n");
scanf("%99s", aname);
if(aname[0] != 0) j = 0;
strcpy(ath.name, aname);
} while(j==1);

Comment: Please don't teach people to use `gets`. It is unsafe, and has been deprecated from modern c. I agree that `scanf("%s", ...)` is not any safer, but a better variant (depending on the needs of OP) would be `scanf("%99s", aname)`

Comment: @HAL9000 i want the name the user entered to be stored in the struct